# How to plot splines of a generalized additive model?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression, gam

Is it possible to plot the scaled spline base of a gam using R like in the following picture?

scaled B-Splines:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You mean the scaled basis functions; the spline would be the sum over the scaled basis functions. I don't know of a canned way, but I doubt it would be difficult to implement with tools already available in my {gratia}  or directly with the {mgcv}  . If you can prepare a minimal example I'll take a look this evening